# Javascript module not appearing in website hosted through CS50 IDE

Tags: javascript, cs50

I'm working on my final project for the course, and struggling to make sense of a bug I'm having with cal-heatmap, a Javascript library that can create heat maps such as Github's contribution calendar.

When I create an HTML file on my computer and open it in Chrome, everything looks perfect.

[Perfect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytO7v.png)

When I create the same HTML file in CS50 IDE and open it after hosting a server through CS50 IDE with Flask/Apache, the thing does not look perfect.

[Not perfect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejLTs.png)

Here is the code, [sourced from this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/heatmaps-using-javascript-part-one/).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  

<head>  
    <title>Cal-Heatmap Samples</title>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cal-heatmap/3.3.10/cal-heatmap.min.js"></script>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cal-heatmap/3.3.10/cal-heatmap.css" />  
</head>  

<body>  
    <div class="container">  
        <div class="page-header">  
            <h2>  
Cal-HeatMap Samples</h2>  
        </div>  
        <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-lg-6">  
                <div class="panel panel-default">  
                    <div class="panel-heading"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-equalizer"></span> Service Call Statistics</div>  
                    <div class="panel-body">  
                        <div id="heatmap-navigation">  
                            <button id="heatmap-previous" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" class="btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>  
                            <button id="heatmap-next" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" class="btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>  
                        </div>  
                        <div id="cal-heatmap">  
                        </div>  
                    </div>  
                </div>  
            </div>  
        </div>  


        <script type="text/javascript">  
            var cal = new CalHeatMap();  
            cal.init({  
                domain: "month",  
                subDomain: "day",  
                cellSize: 20,  
                itemName: ["service ticket", "service tickets"],  
                data: {  
                    "1452019700": 40,  
                    "1454688100": 50,  
                    "1452710900": 5,  
                    "1452883700": 15,  
                    "1453142900": 15,  
                    "1453488500": 30,  
                    "1456239700": 80,  
                    "1453662300": 20,  
                    "1455130100": 60,  
                    "1455562100": 70,  
                    "1455131100": 10,  
                    "1456166900": 30,  
                    "1456399000": 12,  
                    "1451674100": 90  
                },  
                subDomainTextFormat: "%d",  
                range: 3,  
                displayLegend: true,  
                domainMargin: 20,  
                animationDuration: 800,  
                domainDynamicDimension: false,  
                start: new Date(2016, 01, 01),  
                end: new Date(2016, 02, 26),  
                scale: [10, 20, 80],  
                previousSelector: "#heatmap-previous",  
                nextSelector: "#heatmap-next",  
            });  
        </script>  
</body>  

</html>
```

What gives? Why am I getting different results with identical code?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The code you posted does show "perfect" result. So without further info we can only guess. My guess is, that your paths to CDNs will just don't work.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phix, I could kiss you!!

As an amateur, I clearly do not have the habit of snooping the Chrome console. When I did at your behest, the problem was clear as crystal:

Cloud9 (CS50's cloud-based IDE) does not let you link to resources that merely follow HTTP instead of HTTPS.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwtts.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrPOD.png)

I fixed the problem by replaced all of the vanilla "http://" in the previously provided code with "https://".

Thank you, thank you!